# Program.cs Main Function is not hit when Asp.NET core 5 web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hello I'm getting a problem not getting hit into Program.cs . We converted this project from previous .NET core . Now we are using latest .NET core 5 web api . I think when the first application run this project debug mode  should go to Program.cs Main Function but it is not going . Here is my code of Program.cs :

```
       public static async Task Main(string[] args)
         {

        Utility.Log.Init("Webdamad");
        Utility.Log.I("Test");

        platform.Check();

        await LoadMasterAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        Models.MyModelName.Init();
        Models.MySecondModel.Init();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        Utility.Log.I("Init End");
        }
```

Here Is Create HostBuilder

```
     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseUrls($"http://*:{platform.port}");
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I think I have some route Problem and From Where should I Check . Thanks in advance . Every Project when The Project run should go to Main Function but here it is not going .

Comment: Do you perhaps have two `Main` methods? You say it doesn't enter this one, so what happens instead?

Comment: Sorry I have One . I checked